# error: unable to access jarfile /home/aK/.sbt/launchers/0/13.6/sbt-launcher.jar

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

[image]

Following instruction on "Integrating Kafka and Storm: Code Examples and State of the Game" - http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/05/27/kafka-storm-integration-example-tutorial/
when I ran "./sbt test"  on the command line, I get an error saying unable to access jarfile /home/aK/.sbt/launchers/0/13.6/sbt-launcher.jar

I can't figure out a solution for it, and I can't find anything quite exactly like this on my search for an answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question will be easier to answer if you give the code in the question instead of providing a url link to a screen shot of the code.

Comment: I don't have a code, this is just an instruction I followed to integrate kafka and spark stream.

Comment: That's Storm, not Spark... And the blog itself is over 4 years old, so any latest, working SBT, Kafka, and Storm versions are much different

Comment: You could look at the Storm repository https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-kafka-client-examples